# let rails website visitors post image to twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm developing a website in rails that should have a button to share an image on the twitter account of the visitor (not a registered user). How should it be done? I've tried the twitter gem, but it posts on the account of the twitter app owner.

Comment: You should use OAuth for the user to login to their Twitter account, then you can use their credentials with the twitter gem to tweet to that visitors account. Here is a link on how to do it in Devise, there is a ton of tutorials out there that you can follow, but I'd start with understanding OAuth itself first: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was a simpler way that didn't require some kind of authentication on my app side, since it doesn't have users and it's expected to not have them. 

I think I can get somehow the visitors (not users) to sign in on twitter via oauth, store their oauth stuff encrypted in a cookie and then use that data to post the image on their account.